# Akeeba Back up error - How to Backup using Akeeba?

Tags: joomla-2.5

[image]

the Manage and Download is red color, and I don't see part 00 button

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can see, there's nothing wrong with your backup. The file name itself is never a download link, and it's always displayed like that. You should be able to use the <kbd>Download</kbd> button if you want to download the file through your browser (you'll get a warning that downloading through your browser might cause errors, just click OK.
(If it *doesn't* work, please specify what kind of error message you get.)

[image: Akeeba Backup error message]

You can also download the backup manually, you'll find it in `JOOMLAROOT/administrator/components/com_akeeba/backup` (unless you've changed the backup directory).

Comment: if i download finished i want to restore the file that i downloaded how do i do to continued if i can't see the part 00 button.

Comment: Restore the file or the website? To restore the website, copy the backup file to the root folder together with `kickstart.php`, browse to `kickstart.php` and follow the prompts. This is all explained very well in the documentation which is easy to find at the link under "How do I restore my backups?" in the screen capture above.

Comment: @NeilRobertson is right, the `Part 00` button is only for downloading your backup, please read the documentation, or ask another question if you're getting error messages.